# Using a nested element's text as a selector in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm looking to scrape the following HTML structure:

```
<p><strong>ID:</strong>547</p>
<p><strong>Class:</strong>foobar</p>
<p><strong>Procedures:</strong>lorem ipsum.</p>
<p>dolor sit amet.</p>
...
<p><strong>Description:</strong>curabitur at orci posuere.</p>
<p>massa nec fringilla.</p>
...
```

I'm not too confident in working with BeautifulSoup and am not too sure how to handle the fact that the identifier for a given section (id, class, procedures and description) is nested inside the first paragraph containing the content for that section.

I'm trying to get somewhere along the lines of the following:

```
{
    'id': 547,
    'class': 'foobar',
    'procedures': 'lorem ipsum. dolor sit amet.'
    'description': 'curabitur at orci posuere. massa nec fringilla.'
}
```

Comment: this is a dictionnary, so you use a normal `str.format()` and put the `dict.values()` in them

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. I'm looking for a way to take apart the HTML structure above and throw it into the dictionary.

Comment: ah, sorry, i thought you want to make the inverse (from the dictionnary to build the html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `element.next_sibling` reference to get the text *following* the `<strong>` tags. For `p` tags without `strong` tags you'd have to append to the last processed key.

Using the `Element.find_all()` method to select all `<p>` tags, loop and update a dictionary:

```
mapping = {}
key = None
for item in soup.find_all('p'):
    if item.strong:
        key = item.strong.get_text(strip=True).rstrip(':')
        value = item.strong.next_sibling.strip()
    else:
        value = mapping[key] + ' ' + item.get_text(strip=True)
    mapping[key] = value
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <p><strong>ID:</strong>547</p>
... <p><strong>Class:</strong>foobar</p>
... <p><strong>Procedures:</strong>lorem ipsum.</p>
... <p>dolor sit amet.</p>
... ...
... <p><strong>Description:</strong>curabitur at orci posuere.</p>
... <p>massa nec fringilla.</p>
... ''')
>>> mapping = {}
>>> key = None
>>> for item in soup.find_all('p'):
...     if item.strong:
...         key = item.strong.get_text(strip=True).rstrip(':')
...         value = item.strong.next_sibling.strip()
...     else:
...         value = mapping[key] + ' ' + item.get_text(strip=True)
...     mapping[key] = value
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(mapping)
{u'Class': u'foobar',
 u'Description': u'curabitur at orci posuere. massa nec fringilla.',
 u'ID': u'547',
 u'Procedures': u'lorem ipsum. dolor sit amet.'}
```

This doesn't convert the ID to an integer; you could use a `try: value = int(value)`, `except ValueError: pass` combo for that if you feel strongly about converting strings representing integers.

Comment: you are missing some of the description and procedure

Comment: This is glorious, thank you! Looks like there's a lot of fun to be had with BeautifulSoup in the future.